# Alternative for absolute?

Tags: css, absolute

1)

```
<div class="testimonials">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Content ONE</p>
      <p>Content TWO</p>
      <p>Content THREE</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="other-content">
    <p>Content Here</p>
  </div>
```

2)In above code i have give `position:absolute` to `<p></p>` tag, so the `other-content` class content is not displayed under the `content` class.

3)I need `other-content` content will be displayed below the `other-content` class.

4)please don't use height, solve the issue.

5)Please check the below link.

6)Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vamsivelaga/4yj33wha/).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

remove the position from `.content p`

try this..

```
.content p{
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #eee;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    }
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4yj33wha/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the both divs (testimonials and other-content) in an extra wrapper div and then set `position:absolute` on that wrapper.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Leywcjyj/1/)

```css
.wpr {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpr">
  <div class="testimonials">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Content ONE</p>
      <p>Content TWO</p>
      <p>Content THREE</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="other-content">
    <p>Other Content Here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```